# Calculate median from exponential random variables

Tags: probability

> A certain town experiences an average of 5 tornadoes in any four year
>   period. The number of years from now until the town experiences its
>   next tornado as well as the number of years between tornadoes have
>   identical exponential distributions and all such times are mutually
>   independent Calculate the median number of years from now until the
>   town experiences its next tornado.

I'm lost as to what I'm supposed to do. What exactly is the question asking? FYI the correct answer is .55

(Finan exam P 34.29)

Answer (score 1):

According to the data, the average is 5/4 tornadoes per year, so you need to calculate the median of exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=1.25$. You can see this calculation in here, for example, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Median_of_Exponential_Distribution (note that they have $\beta=1/\lambda$). The result is $ln(2)/\lambda$.

Comment: So I was doing this but with $\lambda = 4/5$. If we let X=time between tornadoes~exp($\lambda$), E[X] = $\frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{5}{4}$. Wouldn't this imply $\lambda = 4/5$?

Comment: The average time between tornadoes is 4/5 not 5/4 (tornadoes divided by time. The number should be less than 1, as there were 5 tornadoes but only 4 years)/